Exponential convergence of iterated Poincaré map implies asymptotic convergence of trajectories.
Let $p \in \mathcal{U}$ be a periodic point, and let $P : S′ \rightarrow  S$ be the Poincaré map associated to some transverse section $S$ at $p$. Let $z \in S$ such that $P^n(z)$ is defined for all $n \geq0$ and converges exponentially to p: there exist $C > 0$ and $\lambda < 1$ such that $$\|P^n(z) − p\| \leq C\lambda^n\,\,\text{for all}\,\,n ≥ 1.$$
Show that there exists $r \in\mathbb{R}$ such that the trajectory of $z$ is asymptotic to the trajectory of $f^r(p)$: $$\underset{t\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim}\,\|f^t(z) − f^t(f^r(p))\| = 0.$$
My attempt so far: We know that there exists a least period $T>0$ such that $f^T(p)=p$. Let $\Gamma=\{f^t(p):t\in[0,\,T]\}$ and $S$ a transverse section at $p$. Since for $z\in S$ the iterated Poincaré map converges exponentially (in particular, it converges), we know that the trajectory of $z$ is asymptotic to $\Gamma$ at $p$. Since $T$ is the least period, for $t\in (0,\,T),\,f^t(p)\neq p$.
I'm trying to find an argument that shows that $r$ is a multiple of the period, so that the asymptotic convergence follows directly from the above proposition, but I may be missing something.
